# What is the Applet Class in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ on a Mac to run my java applet. But when I add the Applet to the Run Configurations, there is a missing field. What is the applet class? I've been trying tons of things, but I do not know what goes in the applet class field. I've looked everywhere and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Applet class, as [documentation says](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-applet.html) is the class implementing the `java.applet.Applet`. Given the code:

```
package example;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

Applet class would be `example.HelloWorld`.